# Hacer insert en tabla si no existe un registro POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, symfony, doctrine

Estoy intentando haer un insert en una tabla pero solo hacer insert SI el registro que quiero meter no existe, en el caso de que ya exista no hacer nada.

Lo he intentado de esta manera, solo he campbiado los nombres pero el insert es tal cual:

```
INSERT INTO mitabla (campo1, campo2, campo3, campo4, campo5, campo6) 
VALUES (
(SELECT id FROM secciones WHERE nombre = 'MiSeccion'),
                'valor2',
                'valor3',
                'valor4',
                'valor5',
                'valor6')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT campo2 FROM mitabla WHERE UPPER(campo2) = 'CAMPO2');
```

Y me da este error pero no entiendo que es lo que tengo que hacer:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE" LINE 8: WHERE NOT EXISTS
>   (SELECT campo2 FROM mitabla WHER...
>           ^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 297

Pero no funciona... Otra opción de hacerlo?

Estoy usando `doctrine migrations de Symfony`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inserta el resultado de un select de tu misma tabla solo si el campo2 es diferente

por ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO mitabla (campo1, campo2, campo3, campo4, campo5, campo6) 
SELECT
(SELECT id FROM secciones WHERE nombre = 'MiSeccion'),
'valor2',
'valor3',
'valor4',
'valor5',
'valor6'
FROM mitabla as mt
WHERE UPPER(mt.campo2) != 'CAMPO2';
```

Otra opción seria la siguiente

```
INSERT INTO mitabla (campo1, campo2, campo3, campo4, campo5, campo6)
SELECT
    (SELECT id FROM secciones WHERE nombre = 'MiSeccion'),
    'valor2',
    'valor3',
    'valor4',
    'valor5',
    'valor6'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT campo2 FROM mitabla WHERE UPPER(campo2) = 'CAMPO2');
```

Comment: Ha funcionado a medias, me ha insertado 101 registros, no sé si es por algo en especial pero eso es lo que ha hecho,,,

Comment: prueba con la segunda opción similar a la que tienes

Comment: La segunda es la que me ha funcionado, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

haz una consulta y pregunta si tienes un **id** igual que al que estas insertando, y cuenta la cantidad de **row**, si es mayor que cero obvio que existe en la base de datos, te pongo un
ejemplo de como lo he hecho

```
$este= $_POST['este'];
$query2 = "SELECT id FROM tipo_c WHERE nombre = '$este'";
$stmt = $db->prepare( $query2 );
$stmt->execute();
$can = $stmt->rowCount();

if($can == 0){
   $obj_tipo_c->tipo_c= $_POST['este'];

if($obj_tipo_c->create())} // si es cero lo inserto
else    
   echo "ya existe"
```

Comment: No puedo hacerlo de esa manera, porque en las migraciones de Symfony no tengo la conexión a la base de datos como tal entonces no puedo empezar a poner consultas y código php, si pudiero hacerlo así será super sencillo. :(

Comment: ohhh disculpa no habia leido q usabas doctrine migrations de S